# Is simple_format helper in Rails enough to protect against xss?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, xss, html-sanitizing

I read and tested that `simple_format` allows certain html tags.

Is that safe enough to protect again xss? (assuming I don't mind user will put html to make their text pretty) Could this result in xss? or should I keep with `h` method?

Comment: You can't both use the `h` method *and* use `simple_format`. They're mutually exclusive.

Comment: I want to sanitize to keep xss away, but I want to also allow certain tags (in particular, keep the line breaks the user inputs).

Comment: Then use `simple_format`. As stated in the document, it attempts to sanitize its input.

Comment: so thats the question.. does it protect against xss?

Comment: It's the *first thing* listed in [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there was a vulnerability in rails 4.0.0 and 4.0.1 that has now been resolved, so it should be safe. Here's a link to the issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-security-ann/5ZI1-H5OoIM